# R Shiny : how to include histograms in a table to keep them aligned with elements of the table

Tags: r, shiny

the code below produces a table of inputs with 2 rows and 2 columns (to simplify the situation - see picture below). Based on these inputs, I'd like to produce four histograms, and they should be aligned with the input boxes. It's not the case at the moment. Ideally, there should be a blank space below the rownames of the table, then the first(second) column of histograms should be right below the first(second) column of the table.

One option I've thought about is to add the plots directly in the table in the form of "matrix_input[i,j] <- hist(rnorm(n),breaks=10)", where "n <- input[[paste0("C", j,"_A",i)]]". This way, they would definitely be aligned. But I didn't manage it because I didn't succeed in making the table accept plots as elements. A second option is to code the current framework with a table and the plots underneath, but making sure that they are properly aligned.

I've tried many things without success. Can anyone help please ? Any inputs would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

u <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
"My Application",
tabPanel("Component 1",
fluidPage(fluidRow(column(6,tableOutput('decision_Matrix'),plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plots')),column(6))
)),
tabPanel("Component 2")
))

s <- shinyServer(

function(input,output) {

output$decision_Matrix <- renderTable({
  matrix_input <- matrix(data = NA,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
  for (j in 1:2) {
    for (i in 1:2) {
      matrix_input[i,j] <- paste0("<input id='C",j,"_A",i,"' type='number' class='form-control shiny-bound-input'  value='",input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]],"'>")
    }
  }
  rownames(matrix_input) <- c("alternative1","alternative2")
  colnames(matrix_input) <- c("crit1","crit2")
  matrix_input
},include.rownames = TRUE,sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

output$decision_Matrix_plots <- renderPlot({    

  layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2,ncol = 2))
  for (j in 1:2) {
    for (i in 1:2) {
      set.seed(123)
      n <- input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]]
      if (is.null(n) || is.na(n) || n < 1) n <- 1
      hist(rnorm(n),breaks = 10,main=sprintf("histogram of rnorm( %d )",n))
    }
  }
  recordPlot()
})

})
shinyApp(ui = u,server = s)
```

[image]

Comment: There is an argument `offset` in `column` that you can use. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

Comment: Waterling thank you. Actually the width of the column in the table can vary (at the moment, it's alternative1/2, but it could xyz1, or anything). Therefore, using offset won't do the trick in this case. The plots ideally should be produced within a table, so that they are fully aligned with the above input tables. I've used breakpoints and browser() when I try "matrix_plots[i,j] <- hist(rnorm(n),breaks=10)" but it didn't give me any clue as to what could work. I would be very grateful if you have any ideas/suggestions. Thanks. H

Comment: I wonder if to store histogram in a table is the only way? Have you already considered to use `absolutePanel` / `fixedPanel`?  If you are not looking to cover all screen sizes, it could be a possible solution. Verbatim: `The way absolute positioning works in HTML is that absolute coordinates are specified relative to its nearest parent element whose position is not set to static (which is the default), and if no such parent is found, then relative to the page borders` (from shiny Function reference version 0.14.2).